# How to delegate traffic to a specific worker in a Node.JS Cluster? (socket.IO)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm using socket.IO to make the cluster workers Socket.IO servers. Each worker (ws) has an identifier, which both it and the client knows. The worker is limiting connections through .of('namespace'), being the identifier.

I want the master to delegate traffic to workers based on their identifier, ex: worker with identifier abc123 has a connection delegated to it when the client connects using the route /server/abc123.

Is there any way to accomplish this? I'm trying to use Node.JS clusters for .fork and staying on the same port.
Other solutions following these requirements (along with supporting a socket.io server) are welcome.

--U
Need to delegate specifically the initial connection. Prior error was due to namespaces being wonky.

Comment: You will need some sort of "sticky" routing in the cluster so that a given socket.io connection will stay on the same cluster, when doing it's initial http dance during connection and even when reconnecting.  There are a some add-ons that can do that.  See adapters [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/adapter/) for more info.  Discussion about sticky routing [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/using-multiple-nodes/).

Comment: I've got the sticky and adapter stuff set up -- After initial connection, the clients stay with the websocket. The problem is with delegating specifically the initial connection.

Comment: So, this identifier you want to use for cluster assignment exists before there's ever been a socket.io connection?  If so, where does it come from?  Is it in a cookie?  Where is a mapping stored on your server between identifier and target worker process?

Comment: In the context of this question- Yes, the identifier exists before there's been a socket.io connection to a worker. The identifier is established during a previous communication, which includes a large set of sockets (accounts) which are specifically allowed access. The identifier is told to the worker when it is forked -- asin, the Master receives a message which says to create a worker, and includes the identifier and list of accounts which will be allowed to connect to this worker. (Account is verified via JWT token, and compared against list the worker has.)

Comment: So, how does the server know the identifier for an incoming socket.io connection when it first connects?  Is the JWT token in a cookie or in a custom header?  Does the client know which host it's supposed to be connected to?

Comment: Ah, originating URL. /server/abc123. The client does know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea would be you to not use the cluster module, but instead run multiple separate sub-servers (on different ports) that are designed specifically for the incoming socket.io connections.  You don't use the cluster module because you don't want or need the load balancing built into the cluster module because you have your own host assignment mechanism.

Then, when a client wants to make a socket.io connection, it asks your main server which host/port it should connect to via an http request and the server returns it the hostname or IP address and port of the specific server for that client's identifier.  The client then makes a socket.io connection directly to that host/port.

If you ever need a live client to be moved to another host/port, you can send it a socket.io message telling it what the new host/port should be and the client would then disconnect and reconnect to the new host/port.

Of course, any non-connected client can be moved to a new host/port by just changing your server-side mapping table (for example if you add or remove a socket.io host for scale or maintenance reasons).  So, when it next connects, it will go through the same connection process (asking the main server what socket.io host/port to use).

FYI, this type of connection scheme was used by a major instant messaging system.  It allows larger scale than the cluster module because additional socket.io server processes can be on additional servers (or even in different data centers or countries) and is not limited to just different processes on the same host.

> Ah, originating URL. /server/abc123. The client does know

If the originating URL already specifies (in the URL) what the target server process should be, then you could use something like nginx to do the load balancing for you instead of having the client connect directly to a different host/port, though since your client already has the smarts to specify which host it wants, perhaps its still easier to just change the client to connect to a different host/port and then you wouldn't need nginx to do the routing for you.

Comment: I'll mark this as correct. I've reached a point where the identifier is passed through a cookie, but the socket information cannot be passed from Master to Worker as its circular, and json can't serialize it. Using advanced serialization, it fails to clone as its a streambuffer. I've folded and decided to just have something similar to what you proposed -- a request to see what dedicated server, on different ports, it should connect to.

Comment: @Daedaluxs - There is technically in nodejs a way to pass a socket from parent to child (not by serializing, but using a special feature just for a socket), but it won't work for a socket.io connection (because socket.io server state doesn't go with it). It works only for a plain tcp or http socket that is stateless on the server. You cannot serialize a socket because it has reference to a native object (native code tcp socket) which isn't JSON serializable.